# Javascript -remove and then readd iframe element

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to find a way to get my iframe to reload with a different URL. The code is cross domain as it's a script include added to a 3rd party site. I've looked at various techniques to reload the iframe on here but none of them work.

My second approach I think will work, delete the iframe element, create a new element with a new url and then add it back into the dom. However it doesn't seem to get added to the dom again, not sure if it's a pointer issue? Here's a rough outline of my code:

```
var currentMPId = 0;

function createWindow(mpId) {

    var theIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    theIframe.setAttribute("id", "main-iframe");
    theIframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");

if ((document.getElementById("main-iframe") !== null) && (document.getElementById("main-iframe").src !== "")) { /* don't change the iframe src as it's already been loaded */
    if (currentMPId != mpId) { /* if a different id then recreate the iframe */
        var d = document.getElementById('container');
        var oldframe = document.getElementById("main-iframe");
        d.removeChild(oldframe);

        theIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        theIframe.setAttribute("id", "main-iframe");
        theIframe.setAttribute("src", "http://google.co.uk/");

        d.appendChild(theIframe);
    }
}
else {
    theIframe.setAttribute("src", "http://bing.com");
}

theIframe.style.width = "300px";
theIframe.style.height = "200px";
theIframe.style.position = "absolute";
theIframe.style.top = "0px";
theIframe.frameBorder = 0;

var containerDiv = document.getElementById('container');
containerDiv.appendChild(theIframe);


}

createWindow(10);
```

This method gets called multiple times but only works in the first instance, the second time it should open Google... if "currentMPId != mpId" is true.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks,
Colin.

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle to show the issue, your code fragment is using lots of variables that are not defined.

Comment: Sorry, updated the code now so it's valid. http://jsfiddle.net/v79SC/

Comment: The fiddle you posted doesn't "work": *MPiframeWidth is not defined* and *containerDiv is not defined*.

Comment: Definitely "working" now, sorry about the mess up.

Comment: 2nd call now fails on windowId is not defined

Comment: Don't know why JSLint didn't pick it up, changed now.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you can't use theIframe.src = ... ?